# Dividir cada elemento de un array

Tags: javascript

Tengo este array `promedio = [220,230];` y a cada uno necesito dividirlo por `var cantidad = 4;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Un ejemplo simple con [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map), generara un nuevo array en base al que vas a recorrer

```js
const divisor = 4;
const array = [220, 320];
let  resultado = []
resultado = array.map(function(v) {
  return v / divisor;
});

console.log(array.toString(), "array de entrada");
console.log(resultado.toString(), "array de salida");
```

Comment: Me gusta mucho tu idea. Es práctica y con Javascript puro. +1

Comment: Por supuesto, un sistema mucho más simple es mucho más fácil de mantener después ;)

Comment: Esta debería ser la respuesta aceptada, es la manera más simple y elegante de solucionar lo que el autor quiere, +1

Comment: @JackNavaRow agregale la palabra clave `var` a la variable `resultado`, este código no va a funcionar en un entorno `strict`.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes recorrer tu arreglo para acceder a cada uno de los elementos y dividirlo por el numero que necesites. No te devuelvo un array ni actualizo los elementos del array porque me imagino que los vas a utilizar por separado.

```js
var promedio = [220,320];
var cantidad = 4;
for (i = 0; i < promedio.length; i++) { 
    var resultado = promedio[i] / cantidad;
    console.log(resultado);
}
```

Comment: jQuery sale sobrando, y aunque lo sugiera así el OP, también pienso que es importante no sobre usar herramientas cuando estas no se requieren.

Comment: Que esta pregunta se responde sin utilizar jQuery, y luego veo que programadores (que apenas empiezan a aprender Javascript) usan jQuery cuando sus programas no llaman ni una sola función de este.

Comment: Este funciona, es Javascript Puro y esta sencillo +1

Answer (score 1):

Tienes una respuesta con un bucle y otra con `map`, yo te voy a poner una tercera usando [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach). Con `forEach` atraviesas todos los elementos de un array, entonces sólo te queda actualizar el valor:

```js
var promedio = [220, 320];
var resultado = [];
var divisor = 4;

promedio.forEach(function(elemento, indice) {
   resultado[indice] = elemento / divisor;
});

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: Creo que no es una buena idea modificar los valores originales. En este caso puede que no los tenga que volver a necesitar pero... ¿que pasaría si tuviera que utilizar los valores originales para otro tipo de cálculo?

Comment: Cambié un poco el código para que se guarde en otro array y no se modifique el original